# Put the time in French

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, swift3

I try to format the time in French in my iOS app written in Swift 3
Here the data string

`2000-01-01T14:00:00.000Z`

Here method swift 3

```
func get_time_start() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    let timeStart = dateFormatter.date(from: time_start)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: timeStart!);
}
```

On my application gives its 2:00

And I want to display 2:00 p.m.

I used it: `dateFormatter.locale = Locale (identifier: "fr_FR")`
but its not working there have another manipulation do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix both date formats:

```
func get_time_start() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let timeStart = dateFormatter.date(from: time_start)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: timeStart!);
}
```

Better yet, don't use `dateFormat` to convert the `Date` to a String. Instead, set the `timeStyle` so it's formatted properly without the need to force a specific format.

```
func get_time_start() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let timeStart = dateFormatter.date(from: time_start)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = nil
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
    return dateFormatter.string(from: timeStart!);
}
```

In either case, only set the locale if you want all users to see the time formatted in that specific locale (and that would be rare).